# Redis vector search does not return required number of documents for large K

Tags: python, search, redis, vector-search

I have deployed a RedisSearch server to test vector similarity search. I have followed this guide pretty much exactly, **using HNSW algorithm**:

1. [Using Redis as a Vector Database with OpenAI](https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/blob/main/examples/vector_databases/redis/getting-started-with-redis-and-openai.ipynb)

My main goal was to test RedisSearch performance for medium size datasets (~20 million documents) and large number of returned documents (~5_000 to 10_000) because ElasticSearch solution for vector similarity search was very slow once we start increasing `k` and `num_candidates` to return a large resulting set.

We have an embedding model and based on tests with ES it generates adequate embeddings.

So since we only needed to test the performance (time aspect) of Redis VSS, to save time and money on generating real embeddings with our model, I generated fake embeddings for every document by:

```
list(np.random.rand(1024))
```

and then indexed 20 million documents into Redis. So now when I perform search and request 1_000 documents I do get 1_000 documents back consistently.
But requesting 5_000 documents or more, I start getting either empty sets or sets with number of documents less than specified amount.

This part I do not understand. Nowhere in the code I specified that I needed documents with similarity score above some specific value. I just need 5_000 or 10_000 documents with any score.

How can I have Redis VSS return required number of documents with any similarity score?

Search snippet:

```
def search_redis(
    redis_client: redis.Redis,
    user_query: str,
    index_name: str = INDEX_NAME,
    vector_field: str = "embedding",
    return_fields: list = ["id", "user_id", "title", "vector_score"],
    hybrid_fields = "*",
    k: int = 100,
):
    embedded_query = get_fake_embeddings() # 1024 random floats
    base_query = f'{hybrid_fields}=>[KNN {k} @{vector_field} $vector AS vector_score]'
    query = (
        Query(base_query)
         .return_fields(*return_fields)
         .sort_by("vector_score")
         .paging(0, k)
         .dialect(2)
    )
    params_dict = {"vector": np.array(embedded_query).astype(dtype=np.float32).tobytes()}
    results = redis_client.ft(index_name).search(query, params_dict)
    return results.docs
```

Comment: What's your use case that requires you to get 5k-10k documents?

Comment: @PrabhatJha Business logic, for example thousands of documents may have the same user_id and in this case this user_id will crowd out other user_ids but business logic requires that we have documents with diverse user_ids. Probably this could be resolved within Redis, but now we just want KNN search from Redis and the rest of the logic will be handled in downstream Elastic cluster (aggregation, reranking, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a result of the values for the `TIMEOUT` and `ON_TIMEOUT` configuration options, which I'm guessing you haven't touched.

By default, `TIMEOUT` it is 500ms. So, if your query gets long, it'll timeout after 500ms. Easy enough.

*But*, the `ON_TIMEOUT` option determines what happens upon timeout. And it defaults to `RETURN`. So, upon timeout, calls to `FT.SEARCH` will just return what it has found so far.

If you want to see if this is the problem, try setting `ON_TIMEOUT` to `FAIL` and see if it, well, fails. If so, you can disable timeouts by setting `TIMEOUT` to 0.

Details on these options and how to get and set these are [here](https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/basic-constructs/configuration-parameters/) but a quick way to do this would be to use the [FT.CONFIG](https://redis.io/commands/ft.config-set/) command. Like this:

```bash
redis.cloud> FT.CONFIG GET ON_TIMEOUT
1) 1) ON_TIMEOUT
   2) "return"
redis.cloud> FT.CONFIG GET TIMEOUT
1) 1) TIMEOUT
   2) "500"

redis.cloud> FT.CONFIG SET ON_TIMEOUT FAIL
OK
redis.cloud> FT.CONFIG SET TIMEOUT 0
OK

redis.cloud> FT.CONFIG GET ON_TIMEOUT
1) 1) ON_TIMEOUT
   2) "fail"
redis.cloud> FT.CONFIG GET TIMEOUT
1) 1) TIMEOUT
   2) "0"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm using redis-py client and I could not quickly find how to set the `on_timeout` option, but setting the `timeout` on the query object like this `query = (Query(base_query)....timeout(0))` did indeed result in getting 10_000 results much more often. But still in about 20% of the cases I would get an empty set. Do you have any pointers on how to configure `on_timeout` using the redis-py client? I'm really interested in testing it now

Comment: I did try `redis_client.config_set('on_timeout', 'fail')` but I got an error `ResponseError: Unknown option or number of arguments for CONFIG SET - 'on_timeout'`

Comment: Maybe it needs capitalized? Or perhaps there are ACLs restricting it? You could always trying using the `execute_command` function and send in a raw command and see if that reveals more.

Comment: Yes it looks like it was a timeout issue after all. When I tried setting either one of the following settings to some very large number, like this 
`redis_client.ft().config_set('TIMEOUT', '10000000')` XOR `Query(base_query)... .timeout(100_000_000))` I finally started getting consistent results of 10_000 elements in the resulting set. Some queries did take up to 2 seconds (based on time Jupyter cell magic) but most of them were in 0.5 - 1 second range

Comment: BTW setting `on_timeout` to `fail` like this `redis_client.ft().config_set('ON_TIMEOUT', 'fail')` did not seem to have any effect, at least in the Jupyter I was not seeing any errors.